# I have problem with random, and thing according to that

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner coder and I'm writing an application. It was in this code that I made it so that there were 5 rows with buttons, and with 6 buttons in each row. And I need only 2 buttons to light up in red (that is, ColorRedLose), but sometimes 3 light up, and the variables end, end2, end3, end4, end5 are more than 2, although they cannot be more than 2 Maybe there is an error here somewhere, or you can advise how best to write here. I’ve just been racking my brains over this for 2 hours now and nothing comes of it. Here is the code I took all the code so that there are no questions or misunderstandings

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Jackpot : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {

    }
    void Update()
    {

    }

    [Header("Buttons")]
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn1p1;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn1p2;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn1p3;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn1p4;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn1p5;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn1p6;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn2p1;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn2p2;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn2p3;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn2p4;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn2p5;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn2p6;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn3p1;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn3p2;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn3p3;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn3p4;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn3p5;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn3p6;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn4p1;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn4p2;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn4p3;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn4p4;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn4p5;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn4p6;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn5p1;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn5p2;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn5p3;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn5p4;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn5p5;
    [SerializeField] private Button Btn5p6;

    [Header("Colors")]
    [SerializeField] private Button ColorDefault;
    [SerializeField] private Button ColorGame;
    [SerializeField] private Button ColorClick;
    [SerializeField] private Button ColorLose;
    [SerializeField] private Button ColorLoseEnd;

    [Header("InputFields")]
    [SerializeField] private InputField Stavka;
    [SerializeField] private InputField Traps;

    [Header("Texts")]
    [SerializeField] private Text x1;
    [SerializeField] private Text x2;
    [SerializeField] private Text x3;
    [SerializeField] private Text x4;
    [SerializeField] private Text x5;

    bool r1p1 = true;
    bool r1p2 = true;
    bool r1p3 = true;
    bool r1p4 = true;
    bool r1p5 = true;
    bool r1p6 = true;
    bool r2p1 = true;
    bool r2p2 = true;
    bool r2p3 = true;
    bool r2p4 = true;
    bool r2p5 = true;
    bool r2p6 = true;
    bool r3p1 = true;
    bool r3p2 = true;
    bool r3p3 = true;
    bool r3p4 = true;
    bool r3p5 = true;
    bool r3p6 = true;
    bool r4p1 = true;
    bool r4p2 = true;
    bool r4p3 = true;
    bool r4p4 = true;
    bool r4p5 = true;
    bool r4p6 = true;
    bool r5p1 = true;
    bool r5p2 = true;
    bool r5p3 = true;
    bool r5p4 = true;
    bool r5p5 = true;
    bool r5p6 = true;

    bool mine1p1;
    bool mine1p2;
    bool mine1p3;
    bool mine1p4;
    bool mine1p5;
    bool mine1p6;
    bool mine2p1;
    bool mine2p2;
    bool mine2p3;
    bool mine2p4;
    bool mine2p5;
    bool mine2p6;
    bool mine3p1;
    bool mine3p2;
    bool mine3p3;
    bool mine3p4;
    bool mine3p5;
    bool mine3p6;
    bool mine4p1;
    bool mine4p2;
    bool mine4p3;
    bool mine4p4;
    bool mine4p5;
    bool mine4p6;
    bool mine5p1;
    bool mine5p2;
    bool mine5p3;
    bool mine5p4;
    bool mine5p5;
    bool mine5p6;

    int end = 0;
    int end2 = 0;
    int end3 = 0;
    int end4 = 0;
    int end5 = 0;

    int traps;
    int stavka;
    int rnd1;
    int rnd2;
    int rnd3;
    int rnd4;
    int rnd5;

    private void RandomTraps1()
    {
        rnd1 = Random.Range(1, 7);
        if (end < 2 && end != 3)
        {
            if (rnd1 == 1)
            {
                if (r1p1)
                {
                    mine1p1 = true;
                    r1p1 = false;
                    end++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps1();
            }
            if (rnd1 == 2)
            {
                if (r1p2)
                {
                    mine1p2 = true;
                    r1p2 = false;
                    end++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps1();
            }
            if (rnd1 == 3)
            {
                if (r1p3)
                {
                    mine1p3 = true;
                    r1p3 = false;
                    end++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps1();
            }
            if (rnd1 == 4)
            {
                if (r1p4)
                {
                    mine1p4 = true;
                    r1p4 = false;
                    end++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps1();
            }
            if (rnd1 == 5)
            {
                if (r1p5)
                {
                    mine1p5 = true;
                    r1p5 = false;
                    end++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps1();
            }
            if (rnd1 == 6)
            {
                if (r1p6)
                {
                    mine1p6 = true;
                    r1p6 = false;
                    end++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps1();
            }
            RandomTraps1();
        }
        
    }
    private void RandomTraps2()
    {
        rnd2 = Random.Range(1, 7);
        if (end2 < 2 && end2 != 3)
        {
            if (rnd2 == 1)
            {
                if (r2p1)
                {
                    mine2p1 = true;
                    r2p1 = false;
                    end2 += 1;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps2();
            }
            if (rnd2 == 2)
            {
                if (r2p2)
                {
                    mine2p2 = true;
                    r2p2 = false;
                    end2 += 1;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps2();
            }
            if (rnd2 == 3)
            {
                if (r2p3)
                {
                    mine2p3 = true;
                    r2p3 = false;
                    end2 += 1;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps2();
            }
            if (rnd2 == 4)
            {
                if (r2p4)
                {
                    mine2p4 = true;
                    r2p4 = false;
                    end2 += 1;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps2();
            }
            if (rnd2 == 5)
            {
                if (r2p5)
                {
                    mine2p5 = true;
                    r2p5 = false;
                    end2 += 1;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps2();
            }
            if (rnd2 == 6)
            {
                if (r2p6)
                {
                    mine2p6 = true;
                    r2p6 = false;
                    end2 += 1;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps2();
            }
  
            RandomTraps2();
        }
        
    }
    private void RandomTraps3() 
    {
        rnd3 = Random.Range(1, 7);
        if (end3 < 2 && end3 != 3)
        {
            if (rnd3 == 1)
            {
                if (r3p1)
                {
                    mine3p1 = true;
                    r3p1 = false;
                    end++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps3();
            }
            if (rnd3 == 2)
            {
                if (r3p2)
                {
                    mine3p2 = true;
                    r3p2 = false;
                    end3++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps3();
            }
            if (rnd3 == 3)
            {
                if (r3p3)
                {
                    mine3p3 = true;
                    r3p3 = false;
                    end3++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps3();
            }
            if (rnd3 == 4)
            {
                if (r3p4)
                {
                    mine3p4 = true;
                    r3p4 = false;
                    end3++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps3();
            }
            if (rnd3 == 5)
            {
                if (r3p5)
                {
                    mine3p5 = true;
                    r3p5 = false;
                    end3++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps3();
            }
            if (rnd3 == 6)
            {
                if (r3p6)
                {
                    mine3p6 = true;
                    r3p6 = false;
                    end3++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps3();
            }
            RandomTraps3();
        }
        
    }    
    private void RandomTraps4()
    {
        rnd4 = Random.Range(1, 7);
        if (end4 < 2 && end4 != 3)
        {
            if (rnd4 == 1)
            {
                if (r4p1)
                {
                    mine4p1 = true;
                    r4p1 = false;
                    end4++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps4();
            }
            if (rnd4 == 2)
            {
                if (r4p2)
                {
                    mine4p2 = true;
                    r4p2 = false;
                    end4++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps4();
            }
            if (rnd4 == 3)
            {
                if (r4p3)
                {
                    mine4p3 = true;
                    r4p3 = false;
                    end4++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps4();
            }
            if (rnd4 == 4)
            {
                if (r4p4)
                {
                    mine4p4 = true;
                    r4p4 = false;
                    end4++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps4();
            }
            if (rnd4 == 5)
            {
                if (r4p5)
                {
                    mine4p5 = true;
                    r4p5 = false;
                    end4++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps4();
            }
            if (rnd4 == 6)
            {
                if (r4p6)
                {
                    mine4p6 = true;
                    r4p6 = false;
                    end4++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps4();
            }
            RandomTraps4();
        }
        
    }
        
    private void RandomTraps5()
    {
        rnd5 = Random.Range(1, 7);
        if (end5 < 2 && end5 != 3)
        {
            if (rnd5 == 1)
            {
                if (r5p1)
                {
                    mine5p1 = true;
                    r5p1 = false;
                    end5++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps5();
            }
            if (rnd5 == 2)
            {
                if (r5p2)
                {
                    mine5p2 = true;
                    r5p2 = false;
                    end5++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps5();
            }
            if (rnd5 == 3)
            {
                if (r5p3)
                {
                    mine5p3 = true;
                    r5p3 = false;
                    end5++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps5();
            }
            if (rnd5 == 4)
            {
                if (r5p4)
                {
                    mine5p4 = true;
                    r5p4 = false;
                    end5++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps5();
            }
            if (rnd5 == 5)
            {
                if (r5p5)
                {
                    mine5p5 = true;
                    r5p5 = false;
                    end5++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps5();
            }
            if (rnd5 == 6)
            {
                if (r5p6)
                {
                    mine5p6 = true;
                    r5p6 = false;
                    end5++;
                }
                else
                    RandomTraps5();
            }
            RandomTraps5();
        }
        
    }    
    public void StartGame()
    {      
             
        RandomTraps1();               
        RandomTraps2();               
        RandomTraps3();               
        RandomTraps4();               
        RandomTraps5();               

        x1.text = end.ToString();
        x2.text = end2.ToString();
        x3.text = end3.ToString();
        x4.text = end4.ToString();
        x5.text = end5.ToString();
        if (mine1p1)
            Btn1p1.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine1p2)
            Btn1p2.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine1p3)
            Btn1p3.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine1p4)
            Btn1p4.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine1p5)
            Btn1p5.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine1p6)
            Btn1p6.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine2p1)
            Btn2p1.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine2p2)
            Btn2p2.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine2p3)
            Btn2p3.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine2p4)
            Btn2p4.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine2p5)
            Btn2p5.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine2p6)
            Btn2p6.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine3p1)
            Btn3p1.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine3p2)
            Btn3p2.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine3p3)
            Btn3p3.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine3p4)
            Btn3p4.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine3p5)
            Btn3p5.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine3p6)
            Btn3p6.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine4p1)
            Btn4p1.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine4p2)
            Btn4p2.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine4p3)
            Btn4p3.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine4p4)
            Btn4p4.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine4p5)
            Btn4p5.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine4p6)
            Btn4p6.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine5p1)
            Btn5p1.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine5p2)
            Btn5p2.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine5p3)
            Btn5p3.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine5p4)
            Btn5p4.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine5p5)
            Btn5p5.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
        if (mine5p6)
            Btn5p6.image.color = ColorLose.image.color;
       

    }
}
```

I tried everything connected with this, revised the text letter by letter 3 times, checked everything in Unity but there was no problem anywhere, I also wrote to ChatGPT many times for help, but it didn’t help either. I hope that you can help me with this problem

Comment: ick..   im not surprised you cant find out whats going on, thats a heck of a lot of repeated and complicated code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you architecture. The massive repeating variables should be converted to collections.

For Example:

```
[SerializeField]
private Button[] m_Buttons;

[SerializeField]
private bool[] m_Conditionals;
```

Honestly though, accessing them would be better with a dictionary.
You'd need to create an architecture in which you have some way to
identify these.

With that aside, even with the arrays, you can loop through them
instead of having a massive chain of if-statements.

```
for(int i = 0; i < m_Conditionals.Length; i++)
{
    if(m_Conditional[i])
    {
       m_Conditional[i] = false;
       m_OtherConditional[i] = true;
       end++;
    }
}
```

That being said, as to your problem, I'm just going to take a shot in the dark here because I don't understand what the problem is exactly and your naming convention for your variables leaves room for confusion.

Check out:

```
if (end5 < 2 && end5 != 3)
```

**end5** is **always** going to be **not equal to 3** if it's also less than two.

This is true for every one of these conditions, I just picked 5 for some reason.

Edit:
**Also Note**: All your if statements are going to be hit, even if the if statement before them have been hit. I can't quite tell, based on what I'm looking at, but I'd hazard a guess and say this isn't what you want. That could also lead to issues. Everything else aside, it's a waste of function calls.

You should restructure your code, refactor, come up with a new architecture based on loops, rename your variables, and then maybe we can identify the issue.

I don't really spend much time on stackoverflow, so it may be a while before I respond, but I saw this and it looked like you need some help. I'm not sure if you can send private messages on stackoverflow, but if you can, feel free to do so and I'll try and help you out with this one-on-one.

If not, happy coding, good luck, and much love <3

Comment: Yes, this massive copy/paste code screams for collections

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, thanks to you I completely understood arrays and was able to reduce the length of my code by almost 3 times. And the bugs disappeared, everything began to work perfectly. I am very happy and very grateful to you. You know, before this I thought that this code was somehow complicated and too long. But he didn’t dare to change anything. but thanks to you I decided and I succeeded. you're good!

Comment: @Dimonset congratulations brother. One step at a time!

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor that code or it will keep causing problems, like that:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject _rowPrefab;
[SerializeField] private GameObject _buttonPrefab;
[SerializeField] private int _rows = 5;
[SerializeField] private int _columns = 6;

private List<Button> _buttons = new List<Button>();

void Awake()
{
    for(int row = 0; row < _rows; row++)
    {
        var currentRowTransform = Instantiate(_rowPrefab, transform).transform;
        for(int column = 0; column < _columns; column++)
        {
            var currentButton = Instantiate(_buttonPrefab, currentRowTransform).GetComponent<Button>();
            _buttons.Add(currentButton);
        }
    }
}
```

And now you just need to create prefab from empty row and single button, attach them and just setup _rows and _columns however you want without changing layouts, and all your buttons are in single List field without need of 30 Button fields. I'm not sure if that's working, I've not checked it but you should start from that imho.